# Magento TTFB improvements

Tags: magento-1.7

I'm currently working on improvements on load times and Time To First Byte for Magento 1.7.

Server side info:
Dedicated server
Running 1 Magento instance = 3 store views
LAMP setup

Css & js merged, using CDN
Built-in Magento cache enabled

I have attached profiler info from product page and as you can see ttfb is 1000ms.

I have been advised to use Full Page cache and Varnish cache, which I have set up and speed is noticeable on cached pages, but I would be more interested to get actual non-cached results around 200-400ms mark.

Any suggestions and thoughts would be highly appreciated.

[image: Profiler]

Answer (score 1):

`1 sec` for product page loading time is just perfect result. there is nothing you can do, unless you remove some extra blocks like related, also bought, and attributes from product page, or even make your products as `simple`.

there is probably some gain you can get if you switch to `flat` catalog.

```
Css & js merged, using CDN
```

this will not give you any noticeable results, but, if your storage is not SSD, then move Magento cache to Redis and enabling ZendOpcode cache for php will help a lot.

Comment: If 1sec page load would be the case... 1sec is the TTFB, then it takes additional 1.2-1.8 sec to load content.

Flat catalog is enabled, we already use Redis for session will check with ZendOpcode cache

Comment: this is OK :) because full page loading time can be longer. if you really need instant rendering, then you must change your theme design, move javascripts and css up and down to load in non-blocking way... but this is just a waste of time.